# Collapse rows by common variable of list

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, data-science, bioinformatics

I want to collapse the rows of dataframe to create the orthologe group of each othologe and its corresponding genes.

**For example:**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Ortho1 | gene1 |
| Ortho2 | gene2, gene3 |
| Ortho3 | gene4, gene5, gene6 |
| Ortho4 | gene5, gene6 |
| Ortho5 | gene6, gene7 |
| Ortho6 | gene1, gene8 |

**to be :**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Ortho1, Ortho6 | gene1, gene8 |
| Ortho2 | gene2, gene3 |
| Ortho3, Ortho4, Ortho5 | gene4, gene5, gene6, gene7 |

I have tried to `merge` them, however it requires id, which I do not provide by data. Also `for` loop to find `intersect()`. Feels like, there is a simpler way to overcome this bottleneck.

- the original data was like

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Ortho1 | gene1 |
| Ortho2 | gene2 |
| Ortho2 | gene3 |

...

Comment: Is the only rule for defining an ortholog group: They have one or more genes in common?

Comment: @Seth one ortholog can have mulitple genes. one gene can be contirbuted to multiple orthologs. So I want to cluter them as one group. Would this explaination helps you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is similar to a graph with nodes and edges connecting them. One solution would be to use the `igraph` package to take care of finding the non-overlapping groups. You can do

```
library(igraph)
dd %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows(`Column B`) %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame(vertices=rbind(
    data.frame(v=unique(.$`Column A`), type="ortho"), 
    data.frame(v=unique(.$`Column B`), type="gene"))) %>% 
  decompose() %>% 
  purrr::map_df(function(g) {
    data.frame(
      "Column A" = paste((V(g)$name[V(g)$type=="ortho"]), collapse = ","),
      "Column B" = paste((V(g)$name[V(g)$type=="gene"]), collapse = ",")
    )
  })
```

Which will return

```
              Column.A                Column.B
1        Ortho1,Ortho6             gene1,gene8
2               Ortho2             gene2,gene3
3 Ortho3,Ortho4,Ortho5 gene4,gene5,gene6,gene7
```

Comment: thank you for the comment, however after applying the code. I only acquire two column with one row, where all the ortho and gene collapses.

Comment: can you please explain the code a bit more?

Comment: Is your test data different than your actual data? It sounds like in your real data all your values are connected to each other. It's not clear how you would create separate rows in that case.

Comment: actual data is around 9,704 rows bit more than example, however structure-wise same. If I set `graph_from_data_frame` as not directed, would it be better to group them?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's directed or undirected when using `igraph::decompose`. They are still connected.

Comment: applying original data (each ortholog for each gene) to `graph_from_data_frame `  and applying function gives empty rows.

Comment: was there reason you used `tidyr::separate_rows`? seems the function creates weird variable.

Comment: specifying `separate_rows` 's option `sep = ` solved the problem of weird variable (it was prefix of variables). However still the result does not appear. Dataframe looks empty.

Comment: I made it...Your code was working. Foud all my mistakes!